# How to use dplyr::group_by with multiple groups when programming

Tags: r, dplyr, quoting

Okay so it's one of those days where a previously working piece of code suddenly breaks. Here's a reprex of the code in question:

```
test = data.frame(factor1 = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T),
                  factor2 = sample(letters[1:5], 10, replace=T),
                  variable = sample(100:200, 10))

group_vars = c('factor1','factor2') %>% paste(., collapse = ',')

> test %>% dplyr::group_by_(group_vars)
Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:1:8: unexpected ','
1: factor1,
           ^
```

Now I sweaaaar this worked until today. Of course dplyr is trying to do away with the 'x_' functions anyway, but I've tried to plug everything I can think of into group_by()- using combinations of !!, !!!, sym(), quo(), enquo(), etc and can't figure it out. I've tried not pasting the column names together and AT BEST it simply takes the first one and ignores everything else. Most commonly I get the following error message:

> Error: Column `<chr>` must be length 10 (the number of rows) or one, not 2

I've also read over Hadley's dplyr programming guide (https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html), WHICH SEEMS to cover the issue, except that I'm generating the column names internally and not accepting them as arguments to the function. Has anyone come across this or understand quoting well enough to know a solution to this?

Also, to be clear, this works when only using a single grouping variable. The problem is with multiple groups.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `paste`ing and using `group_by_` (deprecated - but it would not work because it is expecting NSE), we can directly use the vector in `group_by_at`

```
library(dplyr)
group_vars <- c('factor1','factor2')
test %>%
     group_by_at(group_vars)
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   factor1, factor2 [10]
#   factor1 factor2 variable
#     <int> <fct>      <int>
# 1       1 d            145
# 2       5 e            119
# 3       4 a            181
# 4       3 e            155
# 5       3 d            164
# 6       3 b            135
# 7       4 e            137
# 8       4 d            197
# 9       2 d            142
#10       2 c            110
```

---

Or another option is to convert to symbols (`syms` from `rlang`) and evaluate (`!!!`) within `group_by`

```
test %>%
      group_by(!!! rlang::syms(group_vars))
```

---

If we go by the route of `paste`, then one option is `parse_expr` (from `rlang`)

```
group_vars = c('factor1','factor2') %>% paste(., collapse = ';')
test %>%
      group_by(!!! rlang::parse_exprs(group_vars))
# A tibble: 10 x 3
# Groups:   factor1, factor2 [10]
#   factor1 factor2 variable
#     <int> <fct>      <int>
# 1       1 d            145
# 2       5 e            119
# 3       4 a            181
# 4       3 e            155
# 5       3 d            164
# 6       3 b            135
# 7       4 e            137
# 8       4 d            197
# 9       2 d            142
#10       2 c            110
```

Comment: Thanks for the very through answer! I tried option #1 (group_by_at) and that works! Much appreciated

Comment: It's now recommended to use `test %>% group_by(across(group_vars))`